# Passing parameters from Controller to Model in Laravel 5

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5

I am having trouble passing parameters from my Controller to my Model in Laravel 5.
**My Model:**

```
class Widget extends Model {
protected $fillable = array('type');

public function widget_fields_with_data($id)
{
    return DB::table('widget_fields')
        ->join('banner_data', function($join) {
            $join->on('banner_data.widget_field_id', '=', 'widget_fields.id')
            ->where('banner_data.banner_id', '=', $id);
        })
        ->select('widget_fields.*', 'banner_data.value');
}}
```

**In My Controller**

```
$widget->widget_fields_with_data('54')->get();
```

This seems to return an **Undefined variable: id** error and I can't figure out why.
If i hardcode the value in the Model everything works okay.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `use()` statement:
`function($join) use($id)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer. You haven't passed the `$id` in inner function.

```
public function widget_fields_with_data($id)
{
    return DB::table('widget_fields')
        ->join('banner_data', function($join) use($id) { // pass $id here
            $join->on('banner_data.widget_field_id', '=', 'widget_fields.id')
            ->where('banner_data.banner_id', '=', $id);
        })
        ->select('widget_fields.*', 'banner_data.value');
}}
```

Comment: **Missing argument 2 for App\Models\Widget::App\Models\{closure}()** on the edited line

Comment: Sorry i made a mistake